# PHP form is not displaying data from MySQL

Tags: php

PHP form is not displaying data from MySQL.   I have a simple 4 text area form that I would like the data in the specific table rows to display in their respective area.

The first display area does display the data from table and specific row
ex: ( I have attempted to use the    endwhile:  but I get an error

```
<?php
//Create Select Query
     $query = "SELECT * FROM worksheet";
     $data = mysqli_query($con, $query);
?>
```

Area 1 - Does display data in area 1 of form

```
<?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
    echo "\r";
    echo $row1['u_i'] ; 
    echo "\r";
    } 
?>
```

Area 2  does not display data from MySQL

```
<?php while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
    echo "\r";
    echo $row2['u_ni'] ; 
    echo "\r";
    } 
?>
```

Area3  does not display data from MySQL

```
<?php while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
    echo "\r";
    echo $row3['nu_i']; 
    echo "\r"; 
    } 
 ?>
```

Area4  does not display data from MySQL

```
<?php while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
    echo "\r";
    echo $row4['nu_i']; 
    echo "\r"; 
    } 
 ?>
```

Someone please show me the way.    Thanks

Comment: And this error is...? There's nothing wrong with your code as-posted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simultaneusly populate multiple drop down lists with data from a mysql table using the same query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778628/simultaneusly-populate-multiple-drop-down-lists-with-data-from-a-mysql-table-usi)

Comment: I know you aren't outputting your data as dropdown lists, but other than that it appears to be the same problem with the same solution.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I am making a very simple worksheet to post "Things to Do"     I am new to PHP.    What is appearing to me is that I am pulling data from each of the table rows and wanting it to display in its respective area.   The 1st area displays, the the remaining areas do not.   Question:  In each of the 4 seperate areas do I need to put a code to tell it to STOP pulling that data from the specified Table Row?    Will this make the new request for the 2nd table start a fresh pull of the data from its respective Tale Row?  and so on

Answer (score 0):

1st you have to push result into array.Then you can display the anywhere as you wish.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM FROM worksheet";
$data_arr=array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

/* fetch object array */
while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
  //push elements into array
   array_push($data_arr,$obj->field_name)
}

/* free result set */
$result->close();
}
```

Display the result.

```
echo "\r";
echo $data_arr[0]['nu_i']; 
echo "\r"; 
..
..
..
echo "\r";
echo $data_arr[3]['nu_i']; 
echo "\r";
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.     I am new to PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  I am new to PHP      I litterly pasted the code into the area at the top of the form for pushing the array.  It does not work  I am getting an error for the closed   }    I then pasted your code into the 4 seperate areas and still received an error.      The code above the "Display the Result"  in your example  where exactly does that go?    Is there any additional code that is needed in the "Display the Result?"   Did you mean to have 2 "FROM FROM" in the $query line?

Comment: Do I need an  endwhile;   in each of the 4 seperate areas?    I have tried using that statement but it produces an error.     What appears to me in the  "while" process, it needs to be stoped so the next  'while" process can take place.    The 1st  "while"  will pull the data and display it.  Starting at the 2nd - 4th area, it appears not to pull the data and does not display anything with the "echo"

Comment: ok.if so can you send me your code with DB script.I'll revamp it.it will make much easier for me to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your offer.  Would it bo ok with you to remote with teamviewer.com?   I am developing this on my computer and using localhast.   Contact me at ccmark100@gmail.com

Comment: no issue.its much easier if you send me zipped source with your DB script.Then i can check it within my PC